# Transmission keeps crashing when a web seed is connected

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, crash

For some reason Transmission is crashing when I download a torrent file with a web seed. For example: I wanted to download the Netrunner 14 release as a torrent file and Transmission said there was 1 web seed. However when downloading the file Transmission is crashing constantly and I'm not able to download the file with a active web seed as a torrent.

When downloading a random torrent file without a web seed it will behave perfectly as it should be.

More people here that have the same with Transmission?

Answer (score 0):

The web seed is most likely [causing transmission to crash](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=16724&p=70348#p70316), I was having the same issue. This has as of now been fixed at least for `transmission-daemon`.

If you're not willing to wait for an update through Ubuntu repositories and have the technical know-how then get the latest [nightly tarball](https://www.transmissionbt.com/download.php); anything upwards from revision 14463 should work.